# INSERT executes without error but no record added into table

Tags: sql-server

I have a large table into which, under certain conditions, I need to insert some records (one by one due to the nature of the logic).

The structure of the table can be simplified as follows:

```
 DECLARE @_MyTable TABLE (ID INT , Text NVARCHAR(64)) ;
```

For this table, there are 3 indices, none of them UNIQUE.

In a consistent way, running insert commands with a specific value for the ID field complete with success (i.e. no error message and the inserted record is shown in a SELECT) except for a specific value for the ID.
For instance, when the ID is 1234 or 1236, the record is inserted without any issue. If the same insert is ran with 1235, however, the execution completes without error condition BUT no record is inserted.

To test it, and to make sure I'm not mistyping anything, I used the following script:

```
DECLARE @_MyTable TABLE (ID INT , Text NVARCHAR(64)) ;
DECLARE @_ID_Value INT = 1234 ;
INSERT INTO @_MyTable (ID         , Text          ) 
             VALUES   (@_ID_Value , 'This is text') ;
```

As stated, running this script assigning different values for the variable `@_ID_Value` work without any issue except if the value is 1235 (this value is just an example of course).

What sort of solution or debugging approach should I try?

Comment: Can you post an example that fully reproduces this?

Comment: Do you have any triggers on your table? I can ensure you that if your insert statement completed with no errors that the row was inserted into the table. Maybe your code has a try/catch block with a catch block that swallows the error? As posted right now this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @EdmCoff, thanks for addressing my question. The actual code is a rather big and complex procedure. within the procedure, I tried setting hardcoded (instead of using a variable) the ID and the behavior is exactly as described (the simplified version included in the initial post.

Comment: @SeanLange, there is indeed a trigger attached to the table but it is currently disabled. Try-catch: yes, in the trigger but, as stated, currently disabled.

Comment: There's no place you can think of that it could hit a rollback? I know you said the trigger is disabled, but perhaps it's not failing on the actual insert, but is getting rolled back after?

Comment: @EdmCoff, nope... Obviously, I'm doing something wrong but I have no clue what it could be, so I'm sort of "brainstorming" here for ideas to look for, no matter how crazy they could look.

Comment: Try this way, INSERT INTO @_MyTable VALUES   (@_ID_Value , 'This is text')

Comment: @TechieWords, I can (though it will take some work as I'm not inserting values into all columns), but... why do you think that using implicit syntax instead of explicit would make a difference?

Comment: Can you use SQL Profiler to log everything for your session and look for something unexpected (not hitting the insert, hitting your trigger somehow, hitting something else with a rollback)? Also, I'm curious how you are confirming your trigger is disabled (selecting is_disabled from sys.triggers?)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way. The values passed here consider it's a simple example pointing, so for simplicity declared them here itself. Hope you will get those by dynamically.

```
DECLARE @_MyTable TABLE (ID INT , Text NVARCHAR(64))

DECLARE @_ID_Value1 INT = 1234 ;
DECLARE @_ID_Value2 INT = 1235 ;
DECLARE @_ID_Value3 INT = 1236 ;
DECLARE @_ID_Value4 INT = 1237 ;

INSERT INTO @_MyTable
VALUES
(@_ID_Value1, 'This is text1'),
(@_ID_Value2, 'This is text2'),
(@_ID_Value3, 'This is text3'),
(@_ID_Value4, 'This is text4')
SELECT * FROM @_MyTable
```

**Output:**

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | This is text1 |
| 1235 | This is text2 |
| 1236 | This is text3 |
| 1237 | This is text4 |

Comment: @halfer, made the changes in output and given it in tabular format instead of image.